Issue with Hover Functionality on 3D Surface Plot in Plotly version 2.35.2
I am experiencing an issue with the hover functionality on a 3D surface plot created using Plotly.
When I move my mouse over the edges of the graph, it seems like the hover interaction does not extend fully to cover all the data. As a result, some data points near the edges are not accessible or visible through the hover template.

As you can see in the picture, I have placed a red cross where the cursor is supposed to be, but it does not show the hover text where I have placed my cursor. (I’m not sure why the cursor is not shown when I took a screenshot, but the cross marks where the cursor should be).
Is this a known issue with Plotly 3D surface plots?
Are there any specific adjustments or workarounds to ensure hover functionality works correctly for edge data points? In the code, if sizex is 3 and sizey is 500, we can access the data just fine, but when we change sizex to 3 and sizey to 1000, I encounter an issue where it doesn’t display the hovertext.
Plotly version am using: 2.35.2.
Here is the code (codepen) :
function generateMockData(sizex, sizey) {
  const z_data = [];
  const x_data = [];
  const y_data = [];

  for (let i = 0; i <= sizey; i++) {
    const row = [];
    for (let j = 0; j <= sizex; j++) {
      row.push(0);
    }
    z_data.push(row);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i <= sizey; i++) {
    const row = [];
    for (let j = 0; j <= sizex; j++) {
      row.push(j);
    }
    x_data.push(row);
  }

  for (let j = 0; j <= sizey; j++) {
    y_data.push(j);
  }

  return { x_data, y_data, z_data };
}

sizex = 3; 
sizey = 1000;
const { x_data, y_data, z_data } = generateMockData(sizex, sizey);

const trace = {
  type: 'surface',
  x: x_data,
  y: y_data,
  z: z_data,
  hovertemplate: 'X: %{x}<br>Y: %{y}<br>Z: %{z}<extra></extra>',
  colorscale: 'Viridis'
};

const layout = {
  title: 'Mock Data 3D Surface',
  autosize: false,
  width: 800,
  height: 800,
  margin: {
    l: 65,
    r: 50,
    b: 65,
    t: 90
  },
  scene: {
    xaxis: { title: 'X Axis' },
    yaxis: { title: 'Y Axis' },
    zaxis: { title: 'Z Axis' }
  }
};

// Render grafen
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [trace], layout);

I have tried various solutions and read through their forums but haven’t had any luck finding a fix for this issue.

Solution 1 :
You can adjust the aspect ratio of plot in order to prevent distortion by explicitly setting the aspect ratio of the scene and also try to restrict the height or width to make it more square-like. Here is some  code :
const layout = {
   title :'',
   autosize : true,
   width : 800,
   height: 800,
   margin: {
      l: 65,
      r: 50,
      b: 65,
      t: 90
   },
  scene: {
     // mention all axes here
     aspectmode : 'cube' // set the aspect ratio to be equal for all axes
  }
 }

Solution 2:


<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>



This will load latest version, which may help you to fix your hover behavior and render issue
Solution 3:
You can set hovermode to closest which ensures that the hover interaction is linked to the closest point on the surface
Using above solution try below code i hope it helps you


<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>

  <script>
    function generateMockData(sizex, sizey) {
      const z_data = [];
      const x_data = [];
      const y_data = [];

      for (let i = 0; i <= sizey; i++) {
        const row = [];
        for (let j = 0; j <= sizex; j++) {
          row.push(0);
        }
        z_data.push(row);
      }

      for (let i = 0; i <= sizey; i++) {
        const row = [];
        for (let j = 0; j <= sizex; j++) {
          row.push(j);
        }
        x_data.push(row);
      }

      for (let j = 0; j <= sizey; j++) {
        y_data.push(j);
      }

      return { x_data, y_data, z_data };
    }

    const sizex = 3;
    const sizey = 1000;
    const { x_data, y_data, z_data } = generateMockData(sizex, sizey);

    const trace = {
      type: 'surface',
      x: x_data,
      y: y_data,
      z: z_data,
      hovertemplate: 'X: %{x}<br>Y: %{y}<br>Z: %{z}<extra></extra>',
      colorscale: 'Viridis'
    };

    const layout = {
      title: 'Mock Data 3D Surface',
      autosize: true,
      width: 800,
      height: 800,
      margin: {
        l: 65,
        r: 50,
        b: 65,
        t: 90
      },
      hovermode: 'closest', // hover is linked to the closest point as discussed in solution 2
      scene: {
        xaxis: { title: 'X Axis' },
        yaxis: { title: 'Y Axis' },
        zaxis: { title: 'Z Axis' },
        aspectmode: 'cube' // may help you for aspect ratio distortion
      }
    };

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [trace], layout);
  </script>
</body>




I have now tried all three options you gave me, but none of them worked when I tested them. I am still experiencing the same problem with the hover text.
I have inserted a link to my code, but unfortunately, I haven’t had any luck with what you provided.
codepen.io/fardoos020202/pen/XJrNKJQ

Bhavi, if you look at my updated post at the top, I have included a picture with an example where I took a screenshot and marked where I have my cursor with a cross. You can see that it does not show the hover text where I have my cursor.
